# How to start a jekyll server with a batch file

Tags: ruby, batch-file

I want to be able to `cd` into a directory and run `bundler exec jekyll serve` (through the Ruby command line) from a batch file

The only way I can run Jekyll is through the "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" program, which is just a shortcut from `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ruby 2.6.1-1-x64 with MSYS2`to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

```
start "" "C:\Users\eleme\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ruby 2.6.1-1-x64 with MSYS2\Start Command Prompt with Ruby"
```

Running the bat files opens cmd which then opens the command prompt with Ruby, but any other commands afterwards are run through the initial cmd (without Ruby)...

Is there a way to be able to run commands in cmd with Ruby through a bat file? Ideally I want to be able to do

```
start "" "C:\Users\eleme\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ruby 2.6.1-1-x64 with MSYS2\Start Command Prompt with Ruby"
cd "..."
bundler exec jekyll serve
```

Comment: Do `call` instead of `start`. If that works let me know so I can post the answer for marking.

Comment: @shadoe2020 It doesn't do anything if I change `start` to `call` (not even open)